# Excel VBA:Insert 2 blank rows in after every odd rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel sheet that is filled,I just need to fill two extra blank rows after every odd row in sheet.How to do this?I want this to done after clicking on a button.
Suggest some answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or something like this?

```
Public Sub InsertRows()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim lngLastRow as long

  lngLastRow = 1000
  For i = 1 To lngLastRow Step 4
   ActiveSheet.Rows(i + 1).Insert xlShiftDown
   ActiveSheet.Rows(i + 2).Insert xlShiftDown
  Next i
End Sub
```

To use this as a button, you will need to paste this into a Module of your workbook. If there isn't one, you'll have to create one. Then you can link this macro to a button or short-key.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Sub extraRows()

i = 1
While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 2, 1)).EntireRow.Insert
        i = i + 4
Wend

End Sub
```